# How to compare width size of screen with size of String?

Tags: java, android, string

So, for my particular reasons, I need to make sure a `String`(placed in a TextView) size (in pixels) does not exceed the width size of the device (in pixels). To get the width of the screen I use:

```
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    try{
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    }
    screenWidth = screenWidth - ((int) (10 * scale + 0.5f)); //takes into account a 10dp margin
```

And to get the length of the String I use:

```
paint.measureText(string);
```

Where string is a `String` object and paint is a `Paint` object. **The problem I'm facing is:** the `measureText` method is saying the `String` is smaller than the length of the screen, even when it is much longer. Have I overlooked something? Is there a better approach to doing this? Any help, suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: To calculate the width of a character, you need to know the size of the character. And that varies with non-mono fonts.

Comment: So, would the formula simply be (size of characters) * (size of the string)? Where (size of characters) should probably equal the largest character size (M) and (size of the string) would equal `paint.measureText` method? And my other question would be how does `paint.measureText()` calculate a size with no reference to character size?

Comment: No, you need to enumerate _each_ character and calculate the size of it. Then add them all together.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was not an easy one to figure out with the code I provided. For the code I provided was correct. The problem was I created the `Paint` object as follows:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

And then I referenced the `measureText(string)` method. The problem with this is that it doesn't take into account the text size I gave this subclass of `TextView`. So, in order to fix this problem all I had to do was to change the above code to:

```
Paint paint = this.getPaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've generally used:

```
 paint.getTextBounds
```

for this type of situation and found it very accurate.

I've also found that overriding `onSizeChanged` in a custom version of the `TextView` (leaving everything else the same) means that I get a direct fix on the size of the view when I need it.